# Как сделать, чтобы скрытые блоки запоминались после закрытия программы?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ позволяет скрывать(сворачивать) текст-блоки, нажимая сбоку на плюсик. Однако если закрыть Notepad++ и открыть заново, то все блоки снова оказываются развернутыми(хотя в интернете проскакивает информация, что должны запоминаться).

Так как же так сделать, чтобы скрытые блоки запоминались после закрытия программы?

Comment: Автор восстановил вопрос, пожалуйста примите его )

Comment: Конечно, спасибо ему :) (еще тогда хотел засчитать, но не смог)

Comment: а ответ был почему-то удалён.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
Файл > Сохранить сессию
```